# Showing $\frac{1+c}{a+b}\leq \varphi$, when $\frac{1}{1+b}\leq a\leq 1$, $\frac{c^2}{a+c}\leq b\leq 1$ and $0\leq c\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, game-theory

The title pretty much says it all.

Let $\varphi\triangleq\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ be the golden ratio.

Let $a,b,c$ be some non-negative numbers such that:

- $\frac{1}{1+b}\leq a\leq 1$
- $\frac{c^2}{a+c}\leq b\leq 1$
- $0\leq c\leq 1$

> **How can we show that $$\frac{1+c}{a+b}\leq \varphi$$ ?**

---

It is worth mentioning that for $a=b=\varphi^{-1}, c=1$, we get $\frac{1+c}{a+b}=\frac{2}{2\varphi^{-1}}=\varphi$.

---

The motivation for this question comes from the analysis of the [price of anarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_of_anarchy) for the following game ($A$ denotes the row-player payoff, $B$ denotes the column's):

$A=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{1+b} & 1 \\
a & \frac{a^2}{a+c} \\
\end{array} \right) $
$B=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{b}{1+b} & c \\
b & \frac{c^2}{a+c} \\
\end{array} \right) $

This game is a special case of a family of resource-selection games I'm studying.

If we have $\frac{1}{1+b}\leq a\leq 1$ and $\frac{c^2}{a+c}\leq b\leq 1$, then there exists a (pure) Nash equilibrium where the row player plays strategy 2 and the column player plays strategy 1.

This gives us a lower bound on the price of anarchy:
$$PoA\geq \frac{1+c}{a+b}$$

Which I would like to bound. 
Easy enough to use Wolfram or such to get the result but I want an analytic argument.

Comment: What's the origin of this problem, what is its motivation?  It looks as though it could be (loosely) related to continued fractions and convergents in some fashion, but beyond that (and beyond just sketching out the shapes of the inequalities) nothing obvious comes to mind...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - I didn't think going into the motivation would help in this question, but I've added the motivation for it. Thanks!

Comment: I think the changes you've made are already a huge improvement; I would suggest leaving it where it is.  (You might consider adding the game-theory tag to it, too, since it's certainly appropriate now.)